# Duda, para transformar dos números a XXXX-XXXXXXXX

Tags: java, string

Estoy convirtiendo dos números al formato **XXXX-XXXXXXXX**, la tarea es sencilla, pero me surgió una duda y es como puedo optimizar esto de mejor manera, no sabia como hacerlo así que vine para preguntar, ahora comenzaré a enumerar las condiciones que debe tener:

- Uno de los números debe estar del **lado izquierdo** del "-" y el otro número del **lado derecho**.
- Al principio los números son literalmente números (que pueden realizar operaciones matemáticas, a eso me refiero) y al final se convierten en una cadena de caracteres con el formato dado.
- **Los números son aleatorios** pero uno de ellos siempre será menor o igual a 4 caracteres y el segundo número siempre será menor o igual a 8 caracteres.
- Y finalmente, si en el primer lado (el lado de 4 caracteres) el número X es menor que 4, agregue "0" al comienzo del número para completarlo, y en el segundo lado (el lado de 8 caracteres) , si el número X también es menor que 8, debe agregar 0 al principio para completarlo.
  Ejemplo de esto último, si recibes el número 11 como primer número, ya que al "11" le faltan 2 caracteres para llegar a 4, debes pasarlo a "0011". Si el segundo número también es menor que 8, se debe realizar la misma tarea.

Como información adicional, mi solución está hecha en Java 17. Una imagen del código que hice.

```java
private String formatOperationNumber(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo){
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = numberOne.toString().length(); i <= 4; i++){
            builder.append("0");
        }
        builder.append(numberOne.toString());
        builder.append("-");

        for(int i = numberTwo.toString().length(); i <= 8; i++){
           builder.append("0");
        }
        builder.append(numberTwo.toString());
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Cualquier idea para mejorar esto. O algo totalmente nuevo, podría usar Higher Order Function o Lambda con arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución no está mal, pero es mucho más legible y sencillo simplemente usar el método `format` de la clase `String` para obtener el formato que necesitas. Solo necesita agregar `"%04d"` para agregar 4 ceros a la izquierda cuando sea necesario. El código se reduciría a:

```java
private String formatOperationNumber(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo){
      return String.format("%04d-%08d",numberOne, numberTwo);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Un detalle es el uso de la condicionales, si le pasas como primer parámetro un numero de 3 o 4 cifras tu código le agregara 0 demás, lo mismo con el segundo parámetro rompiendo con lo establecido **XXXX-XXXXXXXX**

como idea a tu innovación podes hacer uso del método [concat()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-concat-examples/) para cuando se ingrese un numero de 4 cifras y el otro de 8 ya que solo habría q retornar la concatenación de ambos.
lo otro es hacer uso del método [repeat()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-class-repeat-method-in-java-with-examples/) ,para remplazar el uso del bucle for
con lo agregado quedaría así

```
public static String formatOperationNumber(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo){
         var builder=new StringBuilder();
 //si se ingresa una longitud mayor a lo especificado lanzamos un mensaje de error
            if(numberOne.toString ().length ()>4||numberTwo.toString ().length ()>8){
                return "formato establecido xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
 //si se ingresa longitud 4 y 8 respectivamente retornamos la concatenacion de ambos 
            }else if(numberOne.toString ().length ()==4&&numberTwo.toString ().length ()==8){
                return numberOne +"-".concat (numberTwo.toString ());
 //llenamos de 0 tantas veces como la diferencia respectiva de cada parametro con la logitud de este
            }else{
                builder.append ("0".repeat (4 - numberOne.toString ().length ()));
                builder.append (numberOne).append ("-");
        
                builder.append ("0".repeat (8-numberTwo.toString ().length ()));
                builder.append (numberTwo);
            }
        
            return builder.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Según estas respuestas encontré dos resultados:

- De esta forma es la que menos líneas ocupa y la mas legible

```java
    public static String formatOperationNumber(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo){
        return String.format("%04d-%08d",numberOne, numberTwo);
    }
```

- Y en esta solución se ocupa mas líneas pero en pruebas de rendimientos va mejor (Por milésimas)

```java
    private static String formatOperationNumber(Integer numberOne, Integer numberTwo){
        var builder=new StringBuilder();
        if(numberOne.toString().length()==4&&numberTwo.toString().length()==8){
            builder.append(numberOne).append("-").append(numberTwo);
        }else{
            builder.append("0".repeat(4-numberOne.toString().length())).append(numberOne);
            builder.append("-");
            builder.append("0".repeat(8-numberTwo.toString().length())).append(numberTwo);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```